# Why a family of curve $y = c · f(x) + g(x)$ can only be a solution to first-order linear equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This question is from George F. Simmons' Differential equations : theory, technique, and practice. I just began this book and I am learning how to solve some basic first-order linear equation.

This problem states that the solution of a first-order linear equation must be a family of curves of the form
$$
y = c · f(x) + g(x)
$$

Then it requires me to show that the differential equation of any such family is linear and first-order. It seems to me a very strange question. I can attempt to construct an equation, by writing
$$
\frac{y-g(x)}{f(x)}=c
$$
then differentiate both sides, producing a differential equation without arbitrary constant c:
$$
f(x)\frac{dy}{dx}-y=f(x)g'(x)-g(x)f'(x)
$$

But I do not feel like it means that the family of curves cannot be the solution of some higher-order or non-linear differential equations.

Please help me with this.

Comment: A higher order equation will have additional solutions, so that it does not correspond strictly to the given family.